# How to move from an array to a set of files in python?

Tags: python

I try to make some analysis in a set of data, I find a helpful tutorial to make those analysis. This tutorial requires the use of one file which contains concatenated data from a set of files

```
tempTraces = np.load(r'C:\\Users\\user\\2016.06.01-09.41.16_traces.npy')
    for i in range(len(tempTraces)):
        HW = tempHW[i]
        print (tempTraces[i])
        tempTracesHW[HW].append(tempTraces[i])
    print(tempTracesHW)

    # Switch to numpy arrays
    tempTracesHW = [np.array(tempTracesHW[HW]) for HW in range(9)]
    print (len(tempTracesHW[8]))
```

The result is:

```
[ array([[ 0.06835938,  0.0390625 ,  0.07519531, ...,  0.0546875 ,
         0.08886719,  0.02734375],
       [ 0.06542969,  0.04199219,  0.07714844, ...,  0.06152344,
         0.07324219,  0.09472656],
       [ 0.06640625,  0.04101562,  0.07714844, ...,  0.10742188,
         0.13574219,  0.03222656],
       [ 0.06445312,  0.03613281,  0.07519531, ...,  0.14160156,
         0.1171875 ,  0.14257812],
       [ 0.06347656,  0.04003906,  0.07519531, ...,  0.05566406,
         0.08300781,  0.02539062],
       [ 0.06542969,  0.0390625 ,  0.08105469, ...,  0.03222656,
         0.06738281,  0.07714844]]), 

 array([[ 0.06640625,  0.04199219,  0.07519531, ...,  0.02148438,
         0.0859375 ,  0.12695312],
       [ 0.06640625,  0.04199219,  0.078125  , ...,  0.08886719,
         0.02734375,  0.02734375],
       [ 0.06738281,  0.04394531,  0.07910156, ...,  0.06347656,
         0.08496094,  0.02050781],
       ..., 
       [ 0.0546875 ,  0.03320312,  0.07519531, ...,  0.14355469,
         0.0390625 ,  0.06738281],
       [ 0.06152344,  0.03808594,  0.07421875, ...,  0.04882812,
         0.04296875,  0.09082031],
       [ 0.06640625,  0.03515625,  0.07617188, ...,  0.14355469,
         0.04003906,  0.06542969]]), ...]

len(tempTracesHW[8]) = 7
```

In my case data are not concatenated, and I prefer to not concatenate them because it requires a lot of memory, it represents for me a big problem, so I try to convert this code in order to use it with a set of files:

```
path ='C:\\Users\\user\\Traces'
traces= os.listdir(path)
for i in range(len(traces)):
   HW = tempHW[i]
   tempTracesHW.append([np.load(os.path.join(path, trace)) for trace in traces])
print (tempTracesHW)
```

The result  that I have is  wrong:

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], array([[ 0.01437869,  0.01506449,  0.01579909, ...,  0.04166172,
         0.0417285 ,  0.04172079]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.01437869,  0.01506449,  0.01579909, ...,  0.04166172,
         0.0417285 ,  0.04172079]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.01437869,  0.01506449,  0.01579909, ...,  0.04166172,
         0.0417285 ,  0.04172079]], dtype=float32),...


len(tempTracesHW[8])=0
```

I really need help.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to filter the list of files you are getting
from `os.listdir()`. Not every file might contain useful data.
Consider `fnmatch` to match against meaningful file names.

```
from fnmatch import fnmatch 

path ='C:\\Users\\user\\Traces'
traces= [
    file_name for file_name in os.listdir(path) 
              if fnmatch(file_name, "*.dat")
]
for i in range(len(traces)):
   HW = tempHW[i]
   tempTracesHW.append([np.load(os.path.join(path, trace)) for trace in traces])
print (tempTracesHW)
```

Moreover, you might try:

```
for i, trace in enumerate(traces):
   HW = tempHW[i]  # unclear what HW does, assume influence on np.load()
   tempTracesHW.append(np.load(os.path.join(path, trace)))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but it gives me the same results:  [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [array([[ 0.01437869,  0.01506449,  0.01579909, ...,  0.04166172,
         0.0417285 ,  0.04172079]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.01059266,  0.01118085,  0.0117973 , ..., -0.01831369,
        -0.01834194, -0.01837534]], dtype=float32),

Comment: Consider the second change, if 'np.load()' returns still [] for a couple of files you might want to look into that function.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, I am trying to check it

Comment: It doesn't give me what  I need to have :/